# Вопрос по Таненбауму

Tags: архитектура, списки

Сравните применение битовой карты и списка пустот для отслеживания свободного пространства на диске. Диск состоит из 800 цилиндров, на каждом 
из которых 5 дорожек по 32 сектора. Сколько понадобится пустот (неиспользуемых фрагментов), чтобы их список оказался больше, чем битовая карта? Предполагается, что распределяемый блок — это сектор, а для хранения информации о каждом неиспользуемом фрагменте в списке пустот требуется 32 бита.

Comment: Вы хотите получить готовое решение задания из книги Таненбаума или что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Базовая арифметика. Всего секторов = 800х5х32 = 128000. Если хранить битовую карту, то нужно 128000 бит. На хранение информации об одном секторе нужно 32 бита. в этом объеме уместиться информация о 128000 / 32 = 4000 неиспользуемых фрагментов. Отсюдова ответ - больше 4000 неиспользуемых фрагментов.

P.S. числа достаточно круглые и расчеты можно делать даже в уме.

Comment: Большое спасибо!